# Чтение запись Manager.dict в мультрипроцессах

Tags: python, multiprocessing

В цикле запускается фиксированное колличество процессов через multiprocessing

```
    for (i, data) in enumerate(datas):
            exit_event = Event()
            exit_events.append(exit_event)
            thread = Process(target=func, args=(data,i,exit_event))        
            thread.start()
```

Процессы выполняют одно и тоже задание и завершат они свою работу только при ручном прерывании. В самом начале кода создаем Manager

```
    lock = Lock()
    manager = Manager()
    DATA_CONTROL=manager.dict()
```

И в функции func в начале пробую проверить существование ключа

```
            lock.acquire()
            status = DATA_CONTROL.has_key(data)
            lock.release()
```

На что получаю вот такую ошибку

```
  Process Process-2:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
      self.run()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
      self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "script.py", line 311, in func
      status = DATA_CONTROL.has_key(data)
    File "<string>", line 2, in has_key
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 755, in _callmethod
      self._connect()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 742, in _connect
      conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 169, in Client
      c = SocketClient(address)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 304, in SocketClient
      s.connect(address)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
      return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Вопрос - Как избежать ошибки ?
В принципе нужно реализовать переменную в которую могли бы писать и из которой могли бы читать и главный процесс и новые процессы

Answer (score 1):

Приведите весь код, иначе сложно сказать где ошибка.

Вот пример на python3. Есть словарь dct в который по ключу записываются данные и несколько процессов, которые ждут появления данных (каждый процесс проверяет только свой ключ) и при появлении удаляют их из словаря.

```
from multiprocessing import Event, Lock, Process, Manager
import time
import random


def func(dct, lock, event, key):
    while not event.is_set():
        lock.acquire()
        if key in dct:
            print("Remove data: {0}".format(key))
            del dct[key]
        lock.release()


event = Event()
lock = Lock()
manager = Manager()
dct = manager.dict()

procs = []
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for key in keys:
    procs.append(Process(target=func, args=(dct, lock, event, key)))

for proc in procs:
    proc.start()


for i in range(10):
    dct[random.choice(keys)] = i
    time.sleep(1)

event.set()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()

print("END")
```